# Generic Calculator and Generic Number

Tags: c#, linq, generics, calculator, overloading

.NET does not support generic numbers. It is not possible to enforce a generic method with generic argument T that T is a number. The following code will simply not compile:

```
public T DifficultCalculation<T>(T a, T b)
{
    T result = a * b + a; // <== WILL NOT COMPILE!
    return result;
}
Console.WriteLine(DifficultCalculation(2, 3)); // Should result in 8.
```

To overcome this problem I created a class to overcome this, a generic Calculator. Using this calculator, you can do arithmatic operations on a generic type. It is at that moment assumed that the programmer knows what he is doing. The usage would look like:

```
public T DifficultCalculation<T>(T a, T b)
{
    T result = Calculator<T>.Add(Calculator<T>.Multiply(a, b), a);
    return result;
}
Console.WriteLine(DifficultCalculation(2, 3)); // Results in 8.
```

Of coure... this makes the code less readable, so I created another struct to overcome this: `Number<T>`. In this struct I created every operator I could think of. The code could now be revised as:

```
public T DifficultCalculation<T>(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
{
    Number<T> result = a * b + a;
    return (T)result;
}
Console.WriteLine(DifficultCalculation(2, 3)); // Results in 8.
```

I think this can be very handy for some other developers. Before I broadcast it to the world, I want it to be reviewed. If you have any comments about it (about functionality, performance, usability), please let me know!

## Calculator

```
/// <summary>
/// Class to allow operations (like Add, Multiply, etc.) for generic types. This type should allow these operations themselves.
/// If a type does not support an operation, an exception is throw when using this operation, not during construction of this class.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public static class Calculator<T>
{
    static Calculator()
    {
        Add = CreateDelegate<T>(Expression.AddChecked, "Addition", true);
        Subtract = CreateDelegate<T>(Expression.SubtractChecked, "Substraction", true);
        Multiply = CreateDelegate<T>(Expression.MultiplyChecked, "Multiply", true);
        Divide = CreateDelegate<T>(Expression.Divide, "Divide", true);
        Modulo = CreateDelegate<T>(Expression.Modulo, "Modulus", true);
        Negate = CreateDelegate(Expression.NegateChecked, "Negate", true);
        Plus = CreateDelegate(Expression.UnaryPlus, "Plus", true);
        Increment = CreateDelegate(Expression.Increment, "Increment", true);
        Decrement = CreateDelegate(Expression.Decrement, "Decrement", true);
        LeftShift = CreateDelegate<int>(Expression.LeftShift, "LeftShift", false);
        RightShift = CreateDelegate<int>(Expression.RightShift, "RightShift", false);
        OnesComplement = CreateDelegate(Expression.OnesComplement, "OnesComplement",  false);
        And = CreateDelegate<T>(Expression.And, "BitwiseAnd", false);
        Or = CreateDelegate<T>(Expression.Or, "BitwiseOr", false);
        Xor = CreateDelegate<T>(Expression.ExclusiveOr, "ExclusiveOr", false);
    }

    static private Func<T, T2, T> CreateDelegate<T2>(Func<Expression, Expression, Expression> @operator, string operatorName, bool isChecked)
    {
        try
        {
            Type convertToTypeA = ConvertTo(typeof(T));
            Type convertToTypeB = ConvertTo(typeof(T2));
            ParameterExpression parameterA = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "a");
            ParameterExpression parameterB = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "b");
            Expression valueA = (convertToTypeA != null) ? Expression.Convert(parameterA, convertToTypeA) : (Expression)parameterA;
            Expression valueB = (convertToTypeB != null) ? Expression.Convert(parameterB, convertToTypeB) : (Expression)parameterB;
            Expression body = @operator(valueA, valueB);
            if (convertToTypeA != null)
            {
                if (isChecked)
                    body = Expression.ConvertChecked(body, typeof(T));
                else
                    body = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(T));
            }
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T2, T>>(body, parameterA, parameterB).Compile();
        }
        catch
        {
            return (a, b) =>
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Operator " + operatorName + " is not supported by type " + typeof(T).FullName + ".");
            };
        }
    }

    static private Func<T, T> CreateDelegate(Func<Expression, Expression> @operator, string operatorName, bool isChecked)
    {
        try
        {
            Type convertToType = ConvertTo(typeof(T));
            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "a");
            Expression value = (convertToType != null) ? Expression.Convert(parameter, convertToType) : (Expression)parameter;
            Expression body = @operator(value);
            if (convertToType != null)
            {
                if (isChecked)
                    body = Expression.ConvertChecked(body, typeof(T));
                else
                    body = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(T));
            }
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(body, parameter).Compile();
        }
        catch 
        {
            return (a) =>
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Operator " + operatorName + " is not supported by type " + typeof(T).FullName + ".");
            };
        }
    }

    static private Type ConvertTo(Type type)
    {
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(type))
        {
            case TypeCode.Char:
            case TypeCode.Byte:
            case TypeCode.SByte:
            case TypeCode.Int16:
            case TypeCode.UInt16:
                return typeof(int);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds two values of the same type.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Add;

    /// <summary>
    /// Subtracts two values of the same type.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Subtract;

    /// <summary>
    /// Multiplies two values of the same type.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Multiply;

    /// <summary>
    /// Divides two values of the same type.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Divide;

    /// <summary>
    /// Divides two values of the same type and returns the remainder.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Modulo;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the negative value of T.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values, but will throw an OverflowException on unsigned values which are not 0.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public static readonly Func<T, T> Negate;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the negative value of T.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public static readonly Func<T, T> Plus;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the negative value of T.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public static readonly Func<T, T> Increment;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the negative value of T.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public static readonly Func<T, T> Decrement;

    /// <summary>
    /// Shifts the number to the left.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public static readonly Func<T, int, T> LeftShift;

    /// <summary>
    /// Shifts the number to the right.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public static readonly Func<T, int, T> RightShift;

    /// <summary>
    /// Inverts all bits inside the value.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public static readonly Func<T, T> OnesComplement;

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a bitwise OR.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Or;

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a bitwise AND
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> And;

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a bitwise Exclusive OR.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Xor;
}
```

## Number

```
public struct Number<T>
    where T : IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
{
    private readonly T _Value;

    public Number(T value)
    {
        _Value = value;
    }

    #region Comparison

    public bool Equals(Number<T> other)
    {
        return _Value.Equals(other._Value);
    }

    public bool Equals(T other)
    {
        return _Value.Equals(other);
    }

    public int CompareTo(Number<T> other)
    {
        return _Value.CompareTo(other._Value);
    }

    public int CompareTo(T other)
    {
        return _Value.CompareTo(other);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (obj is T)
            return _Value.Equals((T)obj);
        if (obj is Number<T>)
            return _Value.Equals(((Number<T>)obj)._Value);
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (_Value == null) ? 0 : _Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    static public bool operator ==(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return a._Value.Equals(b._Value);
    }

    static public bool operator !=(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return !a._Value.Equals(b._Value);
    }

    static public bool operator <(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return a._Value.CompareTo(b._Value) < 0;
    }

    static public bool operator <=(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return a._Value.CompareTo(b._Value) <= 0;
    }

    static public bool operator >(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return a._Value.CompareTo(b._Value) > 0;
    }

    static public bool operator >=(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return a._Value.CompareTo(b._Value) >= 0;
    }

    static public Number<T> operator !(Number<T> a)
    {
        return new Number<T>(Calculator<T>.Negate(a._Value));
    }

    #endregion
    #region Arithmatic operations

    static public Number<T> operator +(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(Calculator<T>.Add(a._Value, b._Value));
    }

    static public Number<T> operator -(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(Calculator<T>.Subtract(a._Value, b._Value));
    }

    static public Number<T> operator *(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(Calculator<T>.Multiply(a._Value, b._Value));
    }

    static public Number<T> operator /(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(Calculator<T>.Divide(a._Value, b._Value));
    }

    static public Number<T> operator %(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(Calculator<T>.Modulo(a._Value, b._Value));
    }

    static public Number<T> operator -(Number<T> a)
    {
        return new Number<T>(Calculator<T>.Negate(a._Value));
    }

    static public Number<T> operator +(Number<T> a)
    {
        return new Number<T>(Calculator<T>.Plus(a._Value));
    }

    static public Number<T> operator ++(Number<T> a)
    {
        return new Number<T>(Calculator<T>.Increment(a._Value));
    }

    static public Number<T> operator --(Number<T> a)
    {
        return new Number<T>(Calculator<T>.Decrement(a._Value));
    }

    #endregion 
    #region Bitwise operations

    static public Number<T> operator <<(Number<T> a, int b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(Calculator<T>.LeftShift(a._Value, b));
    }

    static public Number<T> operator >>(Number<T> a, int b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(Calculator<T>.RightShift(a._Value, b));
    }

    static public Number<T> operator &(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(Calculator<T>.And(a._Value, b._Value));
    }

    static public Number<T> operator |(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(Calculator<T>.Or(a._Value, b._Value));
    }

    static public Number<T> operator ^(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(Calculator<T>.Xor(a._Value, b._Value));
    }

    static public Number<T> operator ~(Number<T> a)
    {
        return new Number<T>(Calculator<T>.OnesComplement(a._Value));
    }

    #endregion
    #region Casts

    static public implicit operator Number<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Number<T>(value);
    }

    static public explicit operator T(Number<T> value)
    {
        return value._Value;
    }

    #endregion
    #region Other members

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (_Value == null) ? string.Empty : _Value.ToString();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: It is not currently possible to multiply a double with an integer with automatic widening.

Comment: @Kerem: Correct. Calculation with different numeric datatypes does not work. It only works when the types 'T' are the same. I am open for suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

This is a nifty implementation! Only one thought I came up with: I think `Number` is too tightly coupled with `Calculator`. Now I couldn't decouple it completely, due to the operator overloads in `Number`, but I think I made it such that you could sub in mock or different `Calculator`s as needed. I also added `struct` as a generic constraint on `Number<T>` so that `null` checks weren't needed. I don't know of any numerics that aren't represented as `struct`s, so I think that's a reasonable change.

`ICalculator<T>` interface:

```
public interface ICalculator<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds two values of the same type.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    Func<T, T, T> Add { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Subtracts two values of the same type.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    Func<T, T, T> Subtract { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Multiplies two values of the same type.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    Func<T, T, T> Multiply { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Divides two values of the same type.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    Func<T, T, T> Divide { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Divides two values of the same type and returns the remainder.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    Func<T, T, T> Modulo { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the negative value of T.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values, but will throw an OverflowException on unsigned values which are not 0.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    Func<T, T> Negate { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the negative value of T.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    Func<T, T> Plus { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the negative value of T.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    Func<T, T> Increment { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the negative value of T.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    Func<T, T> Decrement { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shifts the number to the left.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    Func<T, int, T> LeftShift { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shifts the number to the right.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    Func<T, int, T> RightShift { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inverts all bits inside the value.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    Func<T, T> OnesComplement { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a bitwise OR.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    Func<T, T, T> Or { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a bitwise AND
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    Func<T, T, T> And { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a bitwise Exclusive OR.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    Func<T, T, T> Xor { get; }
}
```

`Calculator<T>` class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class to allow operations (like Add, Multiply, etc.) for generic types. This type should allow these operations themselves.
/// If a type does not support an operation, an exception is throw when using this operation, not during construction of this class.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class Calculator<T> : ICalculator<T>
{
    private static readonly ICalculator<T> instance = new Calculator<T>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds two values of the same type.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    private readonly Func<T, T, T> add;

    /// <summary>
    /// Subtracts two values of the same type.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    private readonly Func<T, T, T> subtract;

    /// <summary>
    /// Multiplies two values of the same type.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    private readonly Func<T, T, T> multiply;

    /// <summary>
    /// Divides two values of the same type.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    private readonly Func<T, T, T> divide;

    /// <summary>
    /// Divides two values of the same type and returns the remainder.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    private readonly Func<T, T, T> modulo;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the negative value of T.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values, but will throw an OverflowException on unsigned values which are not 0.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    private readonly Func<T, T> negate;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the negative value of T.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    private readonly Func<T, T> plus;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the negative value of T.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    private readonly Func<T, T> increment;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the negative value of T.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    private readonly Func<T, T> decrement;

    /// <summary>
    /// Shifts the number to the left.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    private readonly Func<T, int, T> leftShift;

    /// <summary>
    /// Shifts the number to the right.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    private readonly Func<T, int, T> rightShift;

    /// <summary>
    /// Inverts all bits inside the value.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    private readonly Func<T, T> onesComplement;

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a bitwise OR.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    private readonly Func<T, T, T> or;

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a bitwise AND
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    private readonly Func<T, T, T> and;

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a bitwise Exclusive OR.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    private readonly Func<T, T, T> xor;

    public Calculator()
    {
        this.add = CreateDelegate<T>(Expression.AddChecked, "Addition", true);
        this.subtract = CreateDelegate<T>(Expression.SubtractChecked, "Substraction", true);
        this.multiply = CreateDelegate<T>(Expression.MultiplyChecked, "Multiply", true);
        this.divide = CreateDelegate<T>(Expression.Divide, "Divide", true);
        this.modulo = CreateDelegate<T>(Expression.Modulo, "Modulus", true);
        this.negate = CreateDelegate(Expression.NegateChecked, "Negate", true);
        this.plus = CreateDelegate(Expression.UnaryPlus, "Plus", true);
        this.increment = CreateDelegate(Expression.Increment, "Increment", true);
        this.decrement = CreateDelegate(Expression.Decrement, "Decrement", true);
        this.leftShift = CreateDelegate<int>(Expression.LeftShift, "LeftShift", false);
        this.rightShift = CreateDelegate<int>(Expression.RightShift, "RightShift", false);
        this.onesComplement = CreateDelegate(Expression.OnesComplement, "OnesComplement", false);
        this.and = CreateDelegate<T>(Expression.And, "BitwiseAnd", false);
        this.or = CreateDelegate<T>(Expression.Or, "BitwiseOr", false);
        this.xor = CreateDelegate<T>(Expression.ExclusiveOr, "ExclusiveOr", false);
    }

    public static ICalculator<T> Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds two values of the same type.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public Func<T, T, T> Add
    {
        get
        {
            return this.add;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Subtracts two values of the same type.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public Func<T, T, T> Subtract
    {
        get
        {
            return this.subtract;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Multiplies two values of the same type.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public Func<T, T, T> Multiply
    {
        get
        {
            return this.multiply;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Divides two values of the same type.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public Func<T, T, T> Divide
    {
        get
        {
            return this.divide;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Divides two values of the same type and returns the remainder.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public Func<T, T, T> Modulo
    {
        get
        {
            return this.modulo;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the negative value of T.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values, but will throw an OverflowException on unsigned values which are not 0.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public Func<T, T> Negate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.negate;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the negative value of T.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public Func<T, T> Plus
    {
        get
        {
            return this.plus;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the negative value of T.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public Func<T, T> Increment
    {
        get
        {
            return this.increment;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the negative value of T.
    /// Supported by: All numeric values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="OverflowException"/>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public Func<T, T> Decrement
    {
        get
        {
            return this.decrement;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shifts the number to the left.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public Func<T, int, T> LeftShift
    {
        get
        {
            return this.leftShift;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shifts the number to the right.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public Func<T, int, T> RightShift
    {
        get
        {
            return this.rightShift;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inverts all bits inside the value.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public Func<T, T> OnesComplement
    {
        get
        {
            return this.onesComplement;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a bitwise OR.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public Func<T, T, T> Or
    {
        get
        {
            return this.or;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a bitwise AND
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public Func<T, T, T> And
    {
        get
        {
            return this.and;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a bitwise Exclusive OR.
    /// Supported by: All integral types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"/>
    public Func<T, T, T> Xor
    {
        get
        {
            return this.xor;
        }
    }

    private static Func<T, T2, T> CreateDelegate<T2>(Func<Expression, Expression, Expression> @operator, string operatorName, bool isChecked)
    {
        try
        {
            var convertToTypeA = ConvertTo(typeof(T));
            var convertToTypeB = ConvertTo(typeof(T2));
            var parameterA = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "a");
            var parameterB = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "b");
            var valueA = (convertToTypeA != null) ? Expression.Convert(parameterA, convertToTypeA) : (Expression)parameterA;
            var valueB = (convertToTypeB != null) ? Expression.Convert(parameterB, convertToTypeB) : (Expression)parameterB;
            var body = @operator(valueA, valueB);

            if (convertToTypeA != null)
            {
                body = isChecked ? Expression.ConvertChecked(body, typeof(T)) : Expression.Convert(body, typeof(T));
            }

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T2, T>>(body, parameterA, parameterB).Compile();
        }
        catch
        {
            return (a, b) =>
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Operator " + operatorName + " is not supported by type " + typeof(T).FullName + ".");
            };
        }
    }

    private static Func<T, T> CreateDelegate(Func<Expression, Expression> @operator, string operatorName, bool isChecked)
    {
        try
        {
            var convertToType = ConvertTo(typeof(T));
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "a");
            var value = (convertToType != null) ? Expression.Convert(parameter, convertToType) : (Expression)parameter;
            var body = @operator(value);

            if (convertToType != null)
            {
                body = isChecked ? Expression.ConvertChecked(body, typeof(T)) : Expression.Convert(body, typeof(T));
            }

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(body, parameter).Compile();
        }
        catch
        {
            return a =>
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Operator " + operatorName + " is not supported by type " + typeof(T).FullName + ".");
            };
        }
    }

    private static Type ConvertTo(Type type)
    {
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(type))
        {
            case TypeCode.Char:
            case TypeCode.Byte:
            case TypeCode.SByte:
            case TypeCode.Int16:
            case TypeCode.UInt16:
                return typeof(int);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

`Number<T>` class:

```
public struct Number<T> where T : struct, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
{
    private static readonly ICalculator<T> defaultCalculator = Calculator<T>.Instance;

    private readonly T value;

    public Number(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public bool Equals(Number<T> other)
    {
        return this.value.Equals(other.value);
    }

    public bool Equals(T other)
    {
        return this.value.Equals(other);
    }

    public int CompareTo(Number<T> other)
    {
        return this.value.CompareTo(other.value);
    }

    public int CompareTo(T other)
    {
        return this.value.CompareTo(other);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj != null && (obj is T
            ? this.value.Equals((T)obj)
            : obj is Number<T> && this.value.Equals(((Number<T>)obj).value));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return a.value.Equals(b.value);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return !a.value.Equals(b.value);
    }

    public static bool operator <(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return a.value.CompareTo(b.value) < 0;
    }

    public static bool operator <=(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return a.value.CompareTo(b.value) <= 0;
    }

    public static bool operator >(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return a.value.CompareTo(b.value) > 0;
    }

    public static bool operator >=(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return a.value.CompareTo(b.value) >= 0;
    }

    public static Number<T> operator !(Number<T> a)
    {
        return new Number<T>(defaultCalculator.Negate(a.value));
    }

    public static Number<T> operator +(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(defaultCalculator.Add(a.value, b.value));
    }

    public static Number<T> operator -(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(defaultCalculator.Subtract(a.value, b.value));
    }

    public static Number<T> operator *(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(defaultCalculator.Multiply(a.value, b.value));
    }

    public static Number<T> operator /(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(defaultCalculator.Divide(a.value, b.value));
    }

    public static Number<T> operator %(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(defaultCalculator.Modulo(a.value, b.value));
    }

    public static Number<T> operator -(Number<T> a)
    {
        return new Number<T>(defaultCalculator.Negate(a.value));
    }

    public static Number<T> operator +(Number<T> a)
    {
        return new Number<T>(defaultCalculator.Plus(a.value));
    }

    public static Number<T> operator ++(Number<T> a)
    {
        return new Number<T>(defaultCalculator.Increment(a.value));
    }

    public static Number<T> operator --(Number<T> a)
    {
        return new Number<T>(defaultCalculator.Decrement(a.value));
    }

    public static Number<T> operator <<(Number<T> a, int b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(defaultCalculator.LeftShift(a.value, b));
    }

    public static Number<T> operator >>(Number<T> a, int b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(defaultCalculator.RightShift(a.value, b));
    }

    public static Number<T> operator &(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(defaultCalculator.And(a.value, b.value));
    }

    public static Number<T> operator |(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(defaultCalculator.Or(a.value, b.value));
    }

    public static Number<T> operator ^(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
    {
        return new Number<T>(defaultCalculator.Xor(a.value, b.value));
    }

    public static Number<T> operator ~(Number<T> a)
    {
        return new Number<T>(defaultCalculator.OnesComplement(a.value));
    }

    public static implicit operator Number<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Number<T>(value);
    }

    public static explicit operator T(Number<T> value)
    {
        return value.value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Monad? I don't see any monad in there. The definition of monad is that it has `bind` and `return` functions that behave in a specific way and there is nothing like that here.

Comment: @svick you're right.

Comment: @Jesse: Thank for you review. I greatly appreciate it. I also though about put the struct as a contraint. But what if somebody decides to create his own numeric class (like a vector, or complex or whatever. And he does not create a struct but a class. Than this system would not work anymore. So I left it out, because it costs only one compare with `null` (if I remember correctly). Can you please explain to me how your code is losely coupled?

Comment: @MartinMulder it's looser - not completely decoupled. The key is creating an interface out of `Calculator`. My line `private static readonly ICalculator<T> defaultCalculator = Calculator<T>.Instance;` is what keeps it coupled to the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

1. Have you considered using [`Operator` from MiscUtil](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/genericoperators.html) instead of your `Calculator`?
2. You should never use general `catch`. Instead, catch only the specific exception you're expecting.
3. Since `operatorName` is used just for the exception, I would consider getting the name from the `operator`'s [`Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.method.aspx).
4. `_Value` probably should be exposed as a read-only property, since the cast is not very discoverable.

Comment: 1. Good one: Did not know about it. And since generic numbers is a common problem, I guess more people don't. 2. You are absolutely right. I will try to find out which exception is thrown if an operator is not supported. 3. I ve choosen to use the names op .NET (like `op_Modulus`) without the prefix. These name are sometimes different. 4. Why does it has to be exposed? Do you know about the internals of a TimeSpan or DateTime? If someone wants to access the internal value, he can cast the Number to the original type.

Comment: @MartinMulder Re 4. this is not about exposing internals, as you pointed out, you can already access the value using the cast. But I think it's a good idea to have an alternative way. If you have a `Number<int>`, it's usually simpler to find out that there is a `Value` property than to find that the cast works. Also, some .Net languages (like F#) treat casts differently, though that might not be relevant to you.